# Algebraic structure of the extended real line $\overline{\Bbb R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, measure-theory, logic, soft-question

The extended real line $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is defined to be the set $\overline{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$, where the adjoined symbols $\{\infty,-\infty\}$ represents the "points at infinity" in both positive and negative direction.

$\overline{\Bbb R}$ can be given a topology by declaring that apart from the usual open basis, we let $(a,\infty]$ and $[-\infty,a)$ be open for any $a\in\Bbb R$. This is the two-point compactification, making $\overline{\Bbb R}$ a compact topological space.

However, the algebraic structure of $\overline{\Bbb R}$ seems rather unique. We declare that for any $a\in \Bbb R$,
$$\begin{align}
\infty+a &= \infty \\
-\infty+a &= -\infty \\
\infty+\infty &= \infty \\
-\infty-\infty &= -\infty \\
\frac a{\infty} &= 0 =\frac a{-\infty}
\end{align}$$
 and for $\infty\ge a>0> b\ge -\infty$,
$$\begin{align}
a\cdot\infty &= \infty \\
a\cdot(-\infty) &= -\infty \\
b\cdot\infty &= -\infty \\
b\cdot(-\infty) &= \infty \\
0\cdot\infty &=0 = 0\cdot(-\infty).\\
\end{align}$$
All other combinations, like $\infty-\infty$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, are left undefined.

Yes, these all make sense but I just want to know if it fits into any bigger framework? This clearly is not in accordance with "basics" algebraic structures that we studied in our undergraduate years.

$-\infty$ is not the additive inverse of $\infty$, neither is $\frac a{-\infty}=a\cdot{-\infty}^{-1}$  since ${-\infty}$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.

> Is there a general theory to this kind of algebraic structure?

I am thinking about boolean algebra since $1$ in a boolean algebra also exhibits this kind of `absorbing' behaviour. Since I lack any deep knowledge in the field of algebra, I hope that someone here might be able to give an insight into this.

PS. I tagged "logic" since I think it looks similar to boolean algebra. Please tell me if this is somehow not appropriate.

Comment: First time I see that $0\cdot(\pm\infty):=0$, in many textbooks the $0\cdot\infty$ is left undefined. In the textbook *Analysis I* from Amann and Escher this is the case and the operations $$\frac{x}{0}:=\begin{cases}+\infty,& x>0\\-\infty,&x<0\end{cases}$$ are defined.

Comment: It's a convention used in the context of measure theory as far as I can tell. Like when you have a function with value $\infty$ supported on the set of measure $0$.

Comment: But it can be left undefined, I don't think it would make my question substantially different.

Comment: aha, I see. Yes, they must be different conventions for different purposes.

Comment: I don't want to discourage this question, but maybe a possible right answer is to ask in return -- what is the purpose of studying algebraic structure in general? What would be gained by axiomatizing this system? Do you have another example of a natural mathematical object that has similar properties? (The Riemann sphere? Something with Quaternions?) Having two opposite directions going off to infinity is very special to the real numbers, I think. But I don't know, I just want to bring up this voice.

Comment: @AreaMan I understand your concern, in fact I have thought about the point myself before I brought up this question here. My respond would be no, neither I am trying to generalize it nor have I seen any striking similarity between $\overline{\Bbb R}$ and other structure. The purpose of this question is purely for aesthetic pleasure. Maybe I might be too optimistic in hoping that someone somewhere may have already find a connection between $\overline{\Bbb R}$ and other natural algebraic structures. (continued)

Comment: I am a firm believer that our understanding of an object wouldn't be complete until we can look at it as a part of something bigger, just like how we study a differentiable function as an element of $C^1, C^2, W^{k,p}$ etc. With the same mindset, I looked at the extended real line and I felt that my understanding of it is far from complete. That sole reason motivated this question.

Comment: As long as we are being philosophical and I'm playing devils advocate -- I think $C^1$ helps us understand the concept of differentiability, because it is the "locus" of continuously differentiable functions in the space of all functions. Of course, understanding the concept of differentiability helps you understand individual differentiable functions. But what is the underlying concept that you are trying to understand? The arithmetic rules involving infinity here are designed to make integration theory work well. The underlying concept is integration, and area measurement.

Comment: Well, this might be a bit vague but what I found interesting about $\overline{\Bbb R}$ are: 1.) Algebraic rules that have 'exceptions' for 'special elements'. 2.) Those `special elements' exhibit some kind of absorbing property. 3.) The ability to make sense of $\frac 1{\infty}$ while $\infty^{-1}$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Btw, I found it funny to see you mentioned area/measure when your user name is AreaMan. Was it intensional? :)

Comment: Not intentional - it's named after the character from the onion. BTW, the mechanics of this site are such that I don't get your message unless you tag me with @.

Answer (score 1):

While algebraic structures with partially defined operations are studied, it is much nicer to stick to structures where the binary operation is possible between any pair of elements.

That said, one natural version of what you're describing is the semiring $[0, \infty]$ defined by the operations you've described on just the nonnegative extended real line.

Another natural version is the projective real line where you just adjoin a symbol $\infty$ which acts like a point that glues together the ends of the real line. (There is no $-\infty$ added here, and the ordering of the reals becomes less important as we have "bent it into a circle.")

In this second picture, the problem of dealing with $-\infty$ has disappeared. Secondly, the operations using $\infty$ have a nice explanation with linear-fractional transformations using real numbers. A general linear-fractional transformation looks like this:

$x\mapsto\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are fixed real numbers such that $ad-bc\neq 0$.

If $c=0$, then the transformation maps $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$, and we can safely extend the map to send $\infty\mapsto \infty$ to get a map of the entire projective line onto itself.

When $c\neq 0$, this expression maps $\mathbb R\setminus\{\frac{-d}c\}$ onto $\mathbb R\setminus\{\frac{a}c\}$. To complete the map we would have to figure out where to send $\infty$ and $\frac{-d}{c}$. The nice choice is to send $\frac{-d}{c}\to \infty$ and $\infty\to \frac{a}{c}$.

With these conventions you can work out the consistent definitions of operations including $\infty$ so that most operations take place on the entire projective real line.